# The proxy moz-proxy://host:port is requesting a username and password. The site says: “LDAP”:

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have Integrated the Selenium with JMeter to perform Performance Test, For this I have used Firefox driver Cofig and gecko driver. Script is executing successfully in local window machine But when trying to execute it on Linux server it giving the following error.
"The proxy moz-proxy://host:port is requesting a username and password. The site says: “LDAP”:"

Note:

- gecko driver is compatible with Firefox version.
- username and password passed while setting proxy on server, and also through JMeter command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're behind a [corporate proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) which requires authentication and unfortunately this is not something you can bypass using [Firefox Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/)

You will need to switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and instantiate the browser manually providing the proxy host/port/username/password/etc. Take a look at [Proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Proxy.html) class JavaDoc

Example code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions

Proxy proxy = new Proxy()
proxy.setHttpProxy("http://username:password@proxy-host:proxy.port")
proxy.setSslProxy("http://username:password@proxy-host:proxy.port")

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy)
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options)
driver.get('http://example.com')
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error
javax.script.ScriptException: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: httpProxy must not contain a scheme: http://username:password@host:port